# loop with delay should run 5 times each time

Tags: javascript, loops

I've this function that runs every 10s and it should do that untill j= 50.
It's working allright.
But what i want is that on every interval something gets executed 5 times and 5 gets added to j.
The first loop is executed as it should but the next 2 are not and doesn't seam to execute the code 5 times but more and then it stops.

Not sure if i'm clear enough but perhaps a look at the the code revaels to you what i'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
function botsLoop() {          
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (var startloop = 0; startloop <= 5;startloop++) {
            var dateTime = new Date();  
            ajaxChat.messagedata = ({
                "messageinfo": {
                    "userID": botUserNodes[j].userID,
                    "userName": botUserNodes[j].userName,
                    "userRole": botUserNodes[j].userRole,
                    "UserGender": botUserNodes[j].UserGender,
                    "Profile_Provider": botUserNodes[j].ProfilePro,
                    "Profile_user_name": botUserNodes[j].Profilename,
                    "UserRegion": botUserNodes[j].nameregion,
                    "channelID": botUserNodes[j].channel,
                    "istor": botUserNodes[j].IsTor,
                    "channelName": botUserNodes[j].channelName,
                    "text": 'userenterinchat,' + botUserNodes[j].lat + ', ' + botUserNodes[j].lng + ', ' + botUserNodes[j].namecity + ', ' + botUserNodes[j].nameregion,
                    "dateTime": dateTime
                }
            });

            Onlinelistupdate = {
                "onlinelist": {
                    "userID": botUserNodes[j].userID,
                    "userName": botUserNodes[j].userName,
                    "UserGender": botUserNodes[j].UserGender,
                    "Profile_Provider": botUserNodes[j].ProfilePro,
                    "Profile_user_name": botUserNodes[j].Profilename,
                    "Profile_user_picture": botUserNodes[j].profilepicture,
                    "UserRegion": botUserNodes[j].nameregion,
                    "channelID": botUserNodes[j].channel,
                    "istor": botUserNodes[j].IsTor,
                    "channelName": botUserNodes[j].channelName,
                    "camonoff": botUserNodes[j].camonoff,
                    "ABOUTME": botUserNodes[j].ABOUTME,
                    "lat": botUserNodes[j].lat,
                    "lng": botUserNodes[j].lng,
                    "namecity": botUserNodes[j].namecity,
                    "nameregion": botUserNodes[j].nameregion,
                    "ismobile": botUserNodes[j].ismobile,
                    "namecountry":  botUserNodes[j].namecountry
                }
            };   

            sendBotMsg(ajaxChat.messagedata, ajaxChat.channelID,Onlinelistupdate);      
            j++;   

            if (j < 50) {          
                botsLoop();            
            }

        }
        startloop = 0;
    }, 10000)
}
```

***solution***

```
    function botsLoop() {
              setTimeout(function () {
                if (j < 50) {                     
                  var times = 5;
                  for (var i=0; i < times; i++){
                    console.log('inner loop: ' + (i + 1));
                    j++;
             var dateTime = new Date();  
             ajaxChat.messagedata = ({"messageinfo":{ "userID": botUserNodes[j].userID, "userName": botUserNodes[j].userName, "userRole": botUserNodes[j].userRole,
              "UserGender": botUserNodes[j].UserGender, "Profile_Provider": botUserNodes[j].ProfilePro, "Profile_user_name": botUserNodes[j].Profilename, "UserRegion": botUserNodes[j].nameregion,
             "channelID": botUserNodes[j].channel, "istor": botUserNodes[j].IsTor, "channelName": botUserNodes[j].channelName, "text": 'userenterinchat,' + botUserNodes[j].lat + ', ' + botUserNodes[j].lng + ', ' + botUserNodes[j].namecity + ', ' + botUserNodes[j].nameregion, "dateTime": dateTime}});

             Onlinelistupdate = {"onlinelist":{ "userID": botUserNodes[j].userID, "userName": botUserNodes[j].userName,
             "UserGender": botUserNodes[j].UserGender, "Profile_Provider": botUserNodes[j].ProfilePro, "Profile_user_name": botUserNodes[j].Profilename, "Profile_user_picture": botUserNodes[j].profilepicture, "UserRegion": botUserNodes[j].nameregion,
             "channelID": botUserNodes[j].channel, "istor": botUserNodes[j].IsTor, "channelName": botUserNodes[j].channelName, "camonoff": botUserNodes[j].camonoff, "ABOUTME": botUserNodes[j].ABOUTME, 
              "lat": botUserNodes[j].lat, "lng": botUserNodes[j].lng, "namecity": botUserNodes[j].namecity, "nameregion":  botUserNodes[j].nameregion, "ismobile": botUserNodes[j].ismobile,  "namecountry":  botUserNodes[j].namecountry}};   

            sendBotMsg(ajaxChat.messagedata, ajaxChat.channelID,Onlinelistupdate);    
                  }
                  botsLoop();
                }
              }, 10000);
            }
```

Comment: your code is extremely poor-formatted. Fix it , so that we cam answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably do the trick for you:

```js
var j = 0;

function botsLoop() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (j < 50) {    
      console.log('timeout function');
      var times = 5;
      for (var i=0; i < times; i++){
        console.log('inner loop: ' + (i + 1));
        j++;
      }
      botsLoop();
    }
  }, 10000);
}

botsLoop();
```

I think you can apply this to your needs by yourself.

Comment: when i put j++;  in the for loop it seems to work. :-)

Comment: and       j = j + 5; removed. Now it's working as i want it.

Comment: Updated the OP with the answer. Not sure what to do next. Should i mark the answer that came closest and set me on the right track be the accepted answer?

Comment: I actually have no idea how you should do in a situation like this. Should I update my answer to have the exact answer that did it for you? No clue.

Answer (score 1):

pass initial value to `j` while calling bots loop for the first time , retain that value:

```
function botsLoop(j) {          
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (var startloop = 0; startloop <= 5;startloop++) {
            var dateTime = new Date();  
            ajaxChat.messagedata = ({
                "messageinfo": {
                    "userID": botUserNodes[j].userID,
                    "userName": botUserNodes[j].userName,
                    "userRole": botUserNodes[j].userRole,
                    "UserGender": botUserNodes[j].UserGender,
                    "Profile_Provider": botUserNodes[j].ProfilePro,
                    "Profile_user_name": botUserNodes[j].Profilename,
                    "UserRegion": botUserNodes[j].nameregion,
                    "channelID": botUserNodes[j].channel,
                    "istor": botUserNodes[j].IsTor,
                    "channelName": botUserNodes[j].channelName,
                    "text": 'userenterinchat,' + botUserNodes[j].lat + ', ' + botUserNodes[j].lng + ', ' + botUserNodes[j].namecity + ', ' + botUserNodes[j].nameregion,
                    "dateTime": dateTime
                }
            });

            Onlinelistupdate = {
                "onlinelist": {
                    "userID": botUserNodes[j].userID,
                    "userName": botUserNodes[j].userName,
                    "UserGender": botUserNodes[j].UserGender,
                    "Profile_Provider": botUserNodes[j].ProfilePro,
                    "Profile_user_name": botUserNodes[j].Profilename,
                    "Profile_user_picture": botUserNodes[j].profilepicture,
                    "UserRegion": botUserNodes[j].nameregion,
                    "channelID": botUserNodes[j].channel,
                    "istor": botUserNodes[j].IsTor,
                    "channelName": botUserNodes[j].channelName,
                    "camonoff": botUserNodes[j].camonoff,
                    "ABOUTME": botUserNodes[j].ABOUTME,
                    "lat": botUserNodes[j].lat,
                    "lng": botUserNodes[j].lng,
                    "namecity": botUserNodes[j].namecity,
                    "nameregion": botUserNodes[j].nameregion,
                    "ismobile": botUserNodes[j].ismobile,
                    "namecountry":  botUserNodes[j].namecountry
                }
            };   

            sendBotMsg(ajaxChat.messagedata, ajaxChat.channelID,Onlinelistupdate);      
            j++;   

            if (j < 50) {          
                botsLoop(j);            
            }

        }
        startloop = 0;
    }, 10000)
}

botsLoop(0); // when called first time
```